# Django: Define a form differently when in testing mode

Tags: python, django, testing, django-forms, captcha

I have a customized captcha field. I want to remove that field from a form when displaying it during tests.

My initial thought was to have a `TESTING` variable in a separate settings file that will be supplied as an argument to the test runner command. Then, I could to something like:

```
class CaptchaForm(forms.Form):
    notify_email = forms.EmailField(required=False)
    if not settings.TESTING:
        recaptcha = CaptchaField()
```

I believe this should work.

There might be an even better approach. Any ideas?

### Update

After playing around with the suggestions below, I added this to the test folder's `__init__.py`:

```
    from project.app.forms import CaptchaField
    CaptchaField.clean = lambda x, y: y
```

This worked---without creating a shared `TESTING` setting. Does this look acceptable? Is there a reason that I should not do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can disable captcha in constructor of unit-testing class. Like this:

```
class MyTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
         super(MyTest, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
         settings.TESTING = True
```

Or you can disable captcha field validation in this constructor, for example.

Comment: Your suggestion is in lieu of making a separate test settings file? But I'd still have to define the form as my example above correct? For your second suggestion: How would I go about disabling the captcha field validation? I'm not exactly sure if I understand what you mean there.

Comment: Yes, you can use shared settings or two separate files. Just use "from django.conf import settings" and set TESTING variable. Actually, i'm not fully confident that this hack works. One i can say exactly: everything coded in unit-test constructor would be done before tests run.

Comment: Read documentation about validation ( http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/forms/validation/ ). Before tests start you may add method "clean_recaptcha", that always returns True, to model's class.

Comment: Ahhh okay. My apologies. It was unclear initially but I see what you mean now. I will try this out. Thank you!

Comment: You led me to a solution I like, +1.

Answer (score 0):

I assume `CaptchaField` is your own class. Then you could change the validation method:

```
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

class CaptchaField(Field):
    # ...

    def validate(self, value, model_instance):
        if settings.TESTING:
            return
        else:
            # Do CAPTCHA checking, leading to either
            # raise ValidationError  or
            # return
```

As werehuman already mentioned, you don't really need a separate settings file but can change the setting inside the unit test class.